DraggableComponent.gd:13 @ drag(): Parameter "get_viewport()" is null
I'm trying to develop a pick-up and put-down mechanic in Godot, using composition. I've used only inheritance until now, so I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Also, I'm new to Godot.
When I play the carrot_seedpack scene and I try to move my carrot seed pack I get the following error:
E 0:00:06:0469   DraggableComponent.gd:13 @ drag(): Parameter "get_viewport()" is null.
<C++ Source>   scene/main/canvas_item.cpp:1047 @ get_global_mouse_position()
<Stack Trace>  DraggableComponent.gd:13 @ drag()
             carrot_seedpack.gd:46 @ _physics_process()

These are my classes:
SelectableComponent.gd
extends Node

var selected = false
var selectable_type = 0 # value for type of item that can be collected

func _init(type : int):
    selectable_type = type

func toggle_select(global_state):
    selected = !selected
    if selected:
        global_state.item_selected = selectable_type
    else:
        global_state.item_selected = 0
    return selected


DraggableComponent.gd
extends StaticBody2D

var is_dragging = false

func start_drag():
    is_dragging = true

func stop_drag():
    is_dragging = false

func drag(position, delta, speed):
    if is_dragging:
        return lerp(position,get_global_mouse_position(), speed * delta)
    return position

carrot_seedpack.gd
extends StaticBody2D

var selectable_component_import = preload("res://scripts/crops/SelectableComponent.gd")
var draggable_component_import = preload("res://scripts/crops/DraggableComponent.gd")

@onready var global_state = Global
@onready var anim_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D


var selectable
var draggable

func _ready():
    anim_sprite.play("default")
    selectable = selectable_component_import.new(1)
    draggable = draggable_component_import.new()
    
func _on_area_2d_input_event(_viewport, event, _shape_idx):
        if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
            if selectable.toggle_select(global_state):
                draggable.start_drag()
            else:
                draggable.stop_drag()
                
func _physics_process(delta):
        global_position = draggable.drag(global_position, delta, 80)

Could you please help me?
